# Bouncing animation with OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, animation

I'm trying to create a bouncing ball that can move in the x, y, and z coordinates. The ball originally starts a couple units in the y-axis above the origin. I've managed to figure out how to get my ball to bounce up and down in the y plane, but am having troubles figuring out what I am doing wrong whenever I try adding the x and z trajectories.

```
double initialVelocity = userInputY;
double initVelX = userInputX;
double initVelZ = userInputZ;
double speed = 1/500.0;
double time = 0;
double x, y, z =0;
if (time == 0){
    velocity+= initialVelocity;
    }
time += speed
velocity = velocity - 9.8 * speed;
if (y+velocity < 0.1){ //collision detection against the floor
    velocity *= -1;
}
if (z + initVelZ < 100){ //Collision detection for ceiling of 100 units
    initVelZ *= -1;
}
if (x + initVelX < 50){ //Collision detection for if ball moves 50 units away from origin in x
    initVelX *= -1;
}
else{
     y += velocity;
     x += initVelX;
     z += initVelZ;
}
gl.gltranslated(x, y, z);
glu.gluSphere() //not really that important to specify
```

When I only use my y variable my ball has a bouncing animation but only moves up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparisons for the z and x coordinates look backwards:

```
if (z + initVelZ < 100){ //Collision detection for ceiling of 100 units
    initVelZ *= -1;
}
if (x + initVelX < 50){ //Collision detection for if ball moves 50 units away from origin in x
    initVelX *= -1;
}
```

This inverts the velocity every time the new position is found to be **inside** the bounds. But they need to be inverted when the new position would end up being **outside** the bounds.

Also, you probably need to test for collision with the walls at both ends of each coordinate direction, so that the ball can bounce off all 6 walls.

For example for the z coordinate, the logic could look like this:

```
if (z + initVelZ < 0.0 || z + initVelZ > 100.0) {
    initVelZ *= -1.0;
}
```

Same thing for the other coordinates.